# Keytool alias does not exist

Tags: android, android-mapview, keytool

I am trying to get my `debug.keystore` md5 key so I can get the API key for Google Maps.

I run the command:

```
 keytool –genkeypair -alias armand -keypass pass
```

And then running the command:

```
keytool -list -alias armand -keystore debug.keystore
```

I then enter my password and it gives me the following error:

```
keytool error: java.lang.Exception: Alias <armand> does not exist
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

**This is right a way to get key:**

To get certificate fingerprint (MD5) follow the steps below:

You need to get the keystore file for getting the certificate fingerprint (MD5).
Your keystore file can be found at the following path:

```
C:\Documents and Settings\<username>\Local Settings\Application Data\Android
```

(Or)

```
C:\Documents and Settings\<username>\.android
```

Keystore file name is `debug.keystore`.
Copy the "debug.keystore" file to some other folder (ex: - "D:\Androidkeystore\") (it's user friendly to use).
Open command Prompt and go to the Java installed directory. ("C:\Program Files\Java\\bin")
Then type the below line (given in box) and press enter.

```
keytool.exe -list -alias androiddebugkey -keystore "D:\AndroidKeystore\debug.keystore" -storepass android -keypass android
```

Here the MD5 certificate fingerprint is

```
64:88:A2:FC:AA:9F:B1:B0:CA:E4:D0:24:A8:1E:77:FB
```

This is working, but I am getting small error here:

this is my path-C:\ANDROID\Java\jdk1.6.0\bin>keytool.exe -list -alias androiddebugkey -keystore"C:\ANDROID\debugkey\debug.keystore"-storepass android -keypass android

```
keytool error: java.lang.RuntimeException: Usage error, android is not a 
legal command
```

Comment: @Dr.nik hey you've just ended 2 days of hell. my map wasn't displaying, didn't know you had to run the keytool against the debug.keystore. thanks dude:)

Comment: Can I apply the debug keystore to the production? As the actual keystore doesn't work (alias not found)

Comment: Pls help bro, I m getting this error- keytool error: java.lang.Exception: Alias <androiddebugkey> does not exist ,
but I get the details if I use keytool -v -list -keystore C:\Users\User1\.android\debug.keystore

Answer (score 7):

You are using the wrong keystore.  You will have to use a different keystore.

I got this same error On Fedora, after running this command:

```
keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore androidKey -list -v
```

Error:

```
keytool error: java.lang.Exception: Alias <androiddebugkey> does not exist
java.lang.Exception: Alias <androiddebugkey> does not exist
```

The mistake I made in this case was me using the keystore to sign my android APK project rather than the `debug.keystore` located in `/home/el/.android/debug.keystore`:

I changed it to use the right keystore like this:

```
[el@rosewill .android ]$ keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore /home/el/.android/debug.keystore -list -v
Enter keystore password:  ******
```

And it produced this output:

```
Alias name: androiddebugkey
Creation date: Aug 31, 2013
Entry type: PrivateKeyEntry
Certificate chain length: 1
Certificate[1]:
Owner: CN=Android Debug, O=Android, C=US
Issuer: CN=Android Debug, O=Android, C=US
Serial number: 14be2b38
Valid from: Sat Aug 31 21:43:47 EDT 2013 until: Mon Aug 24 21:43:47 EDT 2043
Certificate fingerprints:
         MD5:  47:D1:3C:AD:3C:6D:49:22:26:01:6B:C8:4D:C0:37:42
         SHA1: 10:96:22:A1:3C:3B:4A:14:2D:B7:5E:62:1D:D7:9B:0B:24:EE:DF:BD
         SHA256: DF:BF:A9:5D:B8:AE:7D:FF:7E:E7:62:84:8F:32:9A:29:19:C6:41:82:83:FA:0B:D0:1B:59:15:AE:4D:D8:38:D1
         Signature algorithm name: SHA256withRSA
         Version: 3

Extensions: 

#1: ObjectId: 2.5.29.14 Criticality=false
SubjectKeyIdentifier [
KeyIdentifier [
0000: 1A 32 1F F0 03 E0 23 34   6F GE 78 CC E3 10 B5 61  .0....)4o.x....a
0010: 6D 6F F1 38                                        mo.8
]
]
```

**For reference, these were the directions I was following:**

From here: https://developers.google.com/+/quickstart/android

In a terminal, run the the Keytool utility to get the SHA-1 fingerprint of the certificate. For the debug.keystore, the password is android.

```
keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore <path-to-debug-or-production-keystore> -list -v
```

Answer (score 2):

This is what worked for me, first go to your JDK/bin dir, in my case this is `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-12.0.1\bin`, click on dir path and write `cmd` to open command prompt or simply open cmd and navigate to your JDK\bin dir.

Then write:

```
keytool -list -v -alias androiddebugkey -keystore %USERPROFILE%\.android\debug.keystore
```

When prompted for password write: `android`