# problem with android map key

Tags: android, google-maps, keytool

Every time I try to use the keytool to get a key for my maps API, it
pops up saying "Keytool is not a valid Win32 application"

I am running it through command line and am using the same command
that is on the android tutorials

Comment: It looks like just a syntax error on your command. It should be -alias androiddebugkey

Comment: D:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin>keytool.exe -list -alias androiddebugkey -keystor
e "D:\Documents and Settings\Dima\.android\debug.keystore"-storepassandroid -key
passandroid
keytool error: java.lang.RuntimeException: Usage error, and is not a legal comma
nd

D:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin>

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6925659/keytool-alias-does-not-exist/6925802#6925802

Comment: keytool.exe -list -alias androiddebugkey -keystor e "D:\Documents and Settings\Dima\.android\debug.keystore"-storepass android -keypass android
-------
check out the spaces between -storepass and android, -keypass and android

Comment: It works but I get this message..see above

Answer (score 0):

I came across this problem as well. I looked at the size of the keytool.exe file, and found it was 0kb. I ended up running the JDK install file again to fix the problem.