# Trouble with google maps api key

Tags: android, google-maps

I exported an android package file and created a new keystore through eclipse.  The app uses google maps.  App works fine in debug mode but after running the apk the app no longer displays the map, only blank tiles.  I had a google maps api key but it's not working for the release version.  I'm assuming that I need a non-debug maps api key for the release.

How can I access the private key I generated to obtain a maps api key?  From what I've read the private key is needed to get a google maps api key.  I can see the generated file for the key at the file location it was saved but cannot open it.

Hope this makes sense.  Thanks in advance!

Comment: this will help you :: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6925659/keytool-alias-does-not-exist/6925802#6925802][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6925659/keytool-alias-does-not-exist/6925802#6925802

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the same keystore you sign your production .apk to register for the Maps API key, since in development, you are using the Debug keystore for your Maps API key.