# facing problem while using google maps?

Tags: android, google-maps

i am working on google maps for my application. where i saw some links which is stating to generate the system key for accessing of google maps in to the app. But while seeing the syntax it is stating to give the path of the key tool. But my sdk do not have key tool file. Am not able to  proceed . Can i download the key tools into the sdk?  any one help me to do this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6925659/keytool-alias-does-not-exist/6925802#6925802

Answer (score 0):

`keytool` comes as a part of JRE. If `java` is in your path, then `keytool` is also there.

Answer (score 0):

if you download the **keytool** from web,then there may be a chance of version mismatch. So try to **re-install** the **java(JDK & JRE)** and add the path variable into the environment variables.